# WebStorm - Mongoose NPM package masks Promise for auto-complete

Tags: mongoose, npm, webstorm

I've come across an odd issue.

In WebStorm, using JavaScript set to ECMAScript 6, if I install the `mongoose` NPM module, and have `project-name/node_modules` as a library (which is default behavior), then the `mongoose` module seems to mask the default `Promise` auto-complete with a partial one.

This partial one recognizes `new Promise()`, but doesn't autocomplete anything for `Promise.`, and tells me that things like `Promise.all()` are un-imported.

Is there a way to tell WebStorm to give one thing (the built-in defintions) priority over `node_modules` so it won't let them override these core things?

Oddly, if I hit `Ctrl+B` to go to the definition of `Promise`, it still takes me to the `lib.es6.promise.d.ts` file which it normally reads from, and doesn't mention `mongoose` as defining Promise.

Comment: looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30297; can't recreate it with `mongoose` module - must be caused by other dependencies in your project

Comment: It may not be exclusively `mongoose`, but `mongoose` was definitely involved. I went through the dependencies one by one. Eventually got down to just `mongoose` and some `babel` modules (no polyfill, which I suspected originally). Removing `mongoose` consistently fixed it, adding back consistently broke it. It might be others. I'll have to see if I can find a minimal set. Thanks for the YouTrack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose 4.x clobbers the global definition of the built in type `Promise`.

In the `/nodes_module/mongoose/lib/index.js` you'll find this definition:

```
/**
 * Returns the current ES6-style promise constructor. In Mongoose 4.x,
 * equivalent to `mongoose.Promise.ES6`, but will change once we get rid
 * of the `.ES6` bit.
 *
 * @method Promise
 * @api public
 */
```

This JSDoc style declaration is overriding the global definition of the built-in Promise type for ES6.

You can *exclude* the `index.js` file from intellisense in Webstorm. Navigate to the file in the file explore, and right click and select "Mark as plain text".

You should use the TypeScript definitions for Mongoose instead of the node module. This can be installed via `npm install @types/mongoose` or alternative download it as a type in the JavaScript libraries in the settings dialog of WebStorm.